# How to create trusted chain of certificates if I have the last certificate?

Tags: tls, authentication, certificate-authority

Good day.
During last two weeks i had been trying to create my xmpp client app which will be connect to the xmpp server via TLS(because server it's using)

My server is:

```
telnet xmpp.odnoklassniki.ru 5222
Trying 217.20.145.69...
Connected to xmpp.odnoklassniki.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If I do:

> openssl s_client -connect xmpp.odnoklassniki.ru:5222 -starttls xmpp
>   -showcerts | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /Users/dmitry/odnoklassniki.pem

`/Users/dmitry/odnoklassniki.pem` is [here](http://pastebin.com/DiXjf2sM)

After this how i do can create the chain of certificates and import it to trusted keystore?

If am using `Adium messenger` it's works fine and in preference's tab i see this:

[image: Adium chain]

Please help me.

Exception thrown by my code:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [*.odnoklassniki.ru]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1764)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:806)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:267)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [*.odnoklassniki.ru]
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(ServerTrustManager.java:144)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1198)
    ... 11 more
```

**UPDATED**

1. I'd downloaded certificate from `https://www.entrust.net/downloads`
2. after this `C:\>keytool -import -alias Root -keystore o.keystore -trustcacerts -file root.cer` i'd got a keystore `o.keystore`
3. in code i'd added this options:

   > config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
   >   config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
   >   config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
   >   config.setSelfSignedCertificateEnabled(true);
   >   config.setExpiredCertificatesCheckEnabled(true);
   >   config.setVerifyRootCAEnabled(true); config.setTruststoreType("JKS");
   >   config.setKeystorePath("/Users/dmitry/o.keystore");
   >   config.setTruststorePath("/Users/dmitry/o.keystore");
   >   config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");

But the same error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: root certificate not trusted of [*.odnoklassniki.ru]
```

**Debug info**

> keyStore is :  keyStore type is : jks keyStore provider is :  init
>   keystore init keymanager of type SunX509 trustStore is: c:\my.keystore
>   trustStore type is : jks trustStore provider is :  init truststore
>   adding as trusted cert:   Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification
>   Authority, OU="(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is
>   incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US   Issuer:
>    CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2006 Entrust, Inc.",
>   OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust,
>   Inc.", C=US   Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x456b5054   Valid from
>   Mon Nov 27 23:23:42 MSK 2006 until Sat Nov 28 00:53:42 MSK 2026

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ] - please do not cross-post between sites. If the [so]moderators think it would be better here, they have the option to migrate it. You can also flag the question to request a migration.

Comment: SO link deleted.

Comment: Dmitry, you may have deleted the [link to the original question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360647/how-to-connect-to-xmpp-server-using-tls-certificate-or-how-to-solve-this-excepti), but it is still a duplicate question, cross-posted on two sites.

Comment: ok. i will request flag my question on SO. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not put a complete chain in a "trusted store". The trusted store contains the keys that you trust *a priori*. Normally, you would have the certificate which *starts* the chain in your trusted store. The SSL server actually sends a complete chain (that's part of the [SSL/TLS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), section 7.4.2). The client then verifies the signature on each certificate in the chain, relatively to the public key found in the previous certificate, and beginning with the root certificate, which is in the trusted store.

In your case, the root CA appears to be "Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority", and that's the certificate you need to put in your trusted store. The default Java trusted store does not contain it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool) for explanations and pointers on how to change that.

Comment: I'll try it. if i'd understood you right i should download `Entrust root CA` from `Entrust.net`, but what info i should provide during registration? (name, company, email, phone) it should my own information or info from the server? after i should create `trusted store` with this root certificate and it's must work properly. Thank you very much!